# Google input tools for sinhala language source code

Tags: indic, google-input-tools

I am interested in the Google input tools for Sinhala language. I used google but I was unable to find the source code for this. But anyway, I found [this](https://github.com/googlei18n/google-input-tools). It is for Chinese language. Does anyone know where I can find the Google input tools for Sinhala language or any other language like Hindi or how I can use the above Chinese toolkit for Sinhala language?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329040/google-input-tools-api-can-it-be-used

Comment: @DhanukaLakshan: Thank you very much for the quick reply. But I am looking for the source code for windows/cloud version where the word suggestions are also shown when I'm typing. Installshield for the windows version can be found [here](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/)

Comment: You're welcome. That's all I could find. Don't know much about this topic. Good luck with the project :) @shan1024